# On click on 1st element, change style of second element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I posted my CSS, HTML and JS (which is a problem for me).
I want to change the CSS of 'nav' with JS, but only on click on the 'button'.

This is why I wrote JS as it is, but it is probably wrong, as it doesn't do anything.

I only show the button on less than width< 700px, that's when I want the user to click on the button to open the full screen navigation, that is previously in-line

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "block";
    }
```

```css
#button {
  display:none;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
  #button{
    display: block;
    font-size: 8vmax;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
  nav {
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<button id="button">☰</button> 
  <nav id="nav">
    <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
    <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
    <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
    <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
    <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
  </nav>
```

EDIT #1:
changed "document.getElementsById("button").onclick = function()"
to "document.getElementById("button").onclick = function()"

Comment: `getElementsById` isn't the one you're looking for. try `getElementById`

Comment: First off, this doesn't exist: getElementsById
It's getElementById on singular. So it makes sense it doesn't work

Comment: Try to see console for errors. On chrome `ctrl + shift + i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you. thanks

```js
function myFunction() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  nav.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

```css
#button{
    display:none;
}   

nav{
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
    #button{
        display: block;
        font-size: 8vmax;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
    nav{
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        top: 100px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        display:none;
    }
    .mystyle{
    display:flex;}
    }
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">
         ☰
    </button> 
    <nav id="nav">
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: YES! This works! Very simple and easy to understand!

Comment: May I ask, can I use this to make the "display:none" again on second click?

Comment: @jan horuk yes with if condition.. you want me to do it??

Comment: I would be glad, but don't want to take advantage of you!

Comment: Well, this didn't work:

if (document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "flex";) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none";
}

Comment: Like this:


function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "flex";
}


if (document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "flex";) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none";
}?

Comment: Whoa! It works wonders!

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

function myFunction(){
    if (document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none") {
        document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "flex";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "flex"){
        document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none";
    }
}

Comment: function myFunction(){ 
if (document.getElementById("nav").style.display == "none") 
{ 

  document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "flex"; 
} 
else
{ 
  document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none"; 
} 
}

Comment: Did mark as solved, but I cannot yet upvote, as i don't have enough those reputation yet.
Thank you again! Will upvote once I get more reputation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typing mistake in your javascript, it should be `getElementById`. and you should listen for the `click` events in button using `addEventListener`

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click',function() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#button{
    display:none;
}   

nav{
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    #button{
        display: block;
        font-size: 8vmax;
        color: #fff;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
    nav{
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        top: 0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
<button id="button">
         ☰
    </button> 
    <nav id="nav">
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
    </nav>
```